# Canceling pending sends errors

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am running Selenium WebDriver scripts on Chrome Browser, version 23. 
The tests run successfully without any error but there is a message:

[0103/143909:ERROR:ipc_sync_channel.cc(378)] Canceling pending sends
[0103/143909:ERROR:ipc_sync_channel.cc(378)] Canceling pending sends

And because of the above error, the result of the test is FAILED.
Here is how I instantiate a chrome browser session:

```
public static boolean setup(String browserType){
    if(browserType.equals("IE")){
        webdriver1 = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    } else if(browserType.equals("Chrome")){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path to  chromedriver.exe");
        webdriver1 = new ChromeDriver();
}
```

Appreciate any feedback from anyone who has resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=159 it has something to do with your browser has not yet finished loading a page, while selenium closes and quits the driver.